# nightwatch.js / Saucelabs - click() not working [ An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@login_submitButton]>]

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I have been trying to run e2e test cases for a React app using Nightwatch.js + Saucelabs, but is facing the below error while .click() method executes.

Error:
An error occurred while running .click() command on : {"status":-1,"state":"","value":"{\"value\": {\"stacktrace\": \"Backtrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00E07DF3+1474035]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00D807D1+919505]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00D1CB43+510787]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CCDB60+187232]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CCD9B5+186805]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CA1BAB+7083]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CA2126+8486]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CA2F00+12032]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00F6231C+1249612]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00EB1575+525221]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00EB1310+524608]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00E15D28+1531176]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00EB1D4A+527226]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00D975F6+1013238]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00D9746F+1012847]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CA1A16+6678]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00CA174A+5962]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x0120992C+4032348]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x774438F4+36]\n\tRtlUnicodeStringToInteger [0x77B35E13+595]\n\tRtlUnicodeStringToInteger [0x77B35DDE+542]\n\", \"message\": \"invalid argument: missing command parameters\", \"error\": \"invalid argument\"}}","errorStatus":-1,"error":"An unknown error has occurred.","httpStatusCode":400}

Below is the page object:

```js
module.exports = {
  url: function () {
    return this.api.launchUrl
  },
  elements: {
    app: { selector: 'div[id="app"]' },
    login_usernameInput: { selector: 'input[id="user_id"]' },
    login_passwordInput: { selector: 'input[id="password"]' },
    login_submitButton: { selector: 'button[id="submit"]' }
  },
  commands: [
    {
      login () {
        return this
          .waitForElementPresent('span[id=welcomeToMyApp]')
          .setValue('@login_usernameInput', process.env.APP_USERNAME)
          .setValue('@login_passwordInput', process.env.APP_PASSWORD)
          .click('@login_submitButton')
          .waitForElementPresent('@app')
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Test code:

```js
module.exports = {
  beforeEach: (browser, done) => {
    browser.page.loginPage()
      .navigate()
      .login()
    done()
  },

  'Test - DQM Page': function (browser) {
    const dqmPage = browser.page.dqmPage()

    dqmPage
      .navigate()
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .click('@nextCountryTab')
      .assert.visible('@nextCountry')
      .end()
  },

  afterEach: (browser, done) => {
    browser.custom().end()

    setTimeout(function () {
      done()
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

All the other steps, before click() in the login() method works perfectly fine. Even the setValue() functions are executed pretty well.

Please note, the submit button is pretty much visible and clickable.

Comment: I've run into the same issue.  I haven't found the fix yet but I think that the cause is related to the Chrome update from June 7th.  I've tried setting browser version to latest-1 but that isn't working so I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by specifying to use the previous version of Chrome (which right now is 74).

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  ... clipped out my other capabilities for brevity ...
  "version": "latest-1"
}
```

I then changed it to specifically say version 74.  Both of these work but I don't want Chrome to upgrade to 76 and then tests start failing again if we haven't finished adopting whatever the real fix is.

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  ... again - clipped for brevity ...
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "version": "74.0"
}
```

What SauceLabs says should work is the following.  It doesn't work for me.  I got this from their blog post at https://wiki.saucelabs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88801611

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  ... clipped other configs again ...
  "goog:chromeOptions": {"w3c": false}
}
```

Comment: Thanks mrtidy.. I changed the version to 74.0 and it works for me now!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by updating to the newest version of Nightwatch. But the update broke other things.  Here is some documentation on what might break after the update.

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Migrating-to-Nightwatch-1.0